# Changing a lot to config new permission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, permissions, authorization, roles, asp.net-mvc-controller

What is the best way of dynamic authorizing users with their roles. Indeed I have some roles that changes overtimes and currently I have this code for some of my `actions` or `contorllers`:

```
     [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,MainFedration,FederationUser")]
        public string ConfirmAccident(int? id) 
        { .... }
```

Then if a role add or change it's permission i should search and change most of actions and roles to config new permission.

What is the best way to remove this redundant work?

Answer (score 2):

The only other way would be to configure the permissions each role has in a database and then subclass `AuthorizeAttribute` and overload the logic for how it determines which roles are allowed by utilizing the database-stored permissions.

However, it should be noted, that this is a problem mostly because you're using roles improperly. I see this all over, even in official Microsoft documentation, which is part of the problem. Something like "Admin" is a *group*; roles are different and should be things like "CanEdit". A group or a user can be assigned roles, so any user in the "Admin" group, would have the role "CanEdit". Then, you don't have to change the roles config on the action because the ability to edit is the ability to edit, no matter which users or groups have it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at how Access Control is organized: https://nsecurity.codeplex.com/. Here's a simple solution which outlines the principles of **Access Control Entries**, **Access Control Lists**, and how access to items, subject to security restrictions is set up. This way of (dis-)allowing users' access to certain items is much like the way it is organized in, say, Windows file system.

The idea is really simple: instead of giving user **permissions** (not) to do this or that, the **items are guarded** and access is granted/denied once a simple condition is satisfied. In other words, security is not geared towards users, but towards "securables". Or, **keys are used to lock/unlock doors, but not to prevent users from moving around**.